# MVC Data being visible to other clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, web-applications, controller

I have little experience with MVC so I am learning as I go along, and hitting some stumbling blocks.

I have started to develop a MVC Web App and just finished a form which calls a web service to get a list of addresses and populates the options within a select with each address.

This works fine, however I've deployed it to the test servers and when I run the site it works, however if my colleague from another client goes to the page, it displays the list of data I ran. Each call to the site should be individual, so not sure why this data is visible to someone else?

View (index.cshtml)

```
namespace AddressLookupSite.Controllers
{
public class AssistedController : Controller
{
    string postcode = "";
    string street = "";
    //model is the list of addresses to be returned to the user
    private static AddressList model = new AddressList();

    // GET: Assisted
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //this may need to be index,models.
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult GetAddresses(string postcode)
    {
        if (postcode == null || postcode == "")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("/Index/");
        }
        //call Addresslookup web service
        AddressLookupWeb ew = new AddressLookupWeb();
        //extract address values from the XML returned from web service
        XmlNode xml = ew.GetAddress(", , , , " + postcode);

        foreach (XmlElement addressInfo in xml)
        {
            foreach (XmlElement teset in addressInfo["Addresses"])
            {
                //add each address item found to the list
                model.listone.Add(new AddressResults { FullAddress = teset["fulladdress"].InnerText });
            }
        }

        //return the list and model back to the index view
        return View("Index", model);


    }
}
```

Model (AddressResults)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AddressLookupSite.Models
{
public class AddressResults
{
    public string FullAddress { get; set; }
}
}
```

Model (AddressResults)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AddressLookupSite.Models
{
public class AddressList
{
    public List<AddressResults> listone = new List<AddressResults>();
}
}
```

The view is pretty standard and accesses the model, outputting the contents of the model to the select, it also uses some JavaScript to do some basic code.

The issue is definitely server side, it should not allow another user to be able to intercept the form, especially since the form will later include personal data. This makes me think, if I was in the middle of completing a form and someone else opened the page, this would then give them the data from the controller when it shouldn't happen like that.

Any advice much appreciated, as I say I'm new to this and only been developing internal apps previously to run processes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the result model as `static` and assign it inline:

```
//model is the list of addresses to be returned to the user
private static AddressList model = new AddressList();
```

This means that there will only be one instance of this class. That would seem to be the cause of everyone getting the same results.

Remove the static or construct the instance in the method that will use it. Either will give each caller their own copy.

Comment: If i take the static out, does this mean that particular user will lose their data if they went back to the homepage for example? once the user submits the form, they're taken to /assisted/getAddresses but the way i want it is that if they were to navigate back to /assisted/ the form would still have their data.

Comment: PS Thanks for the answer.